# Finding the value of the following double integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, multiple-integral

The following question appeared in the American Mathematical Monthly (AMM), problem 12247, Vol.128, April 2021.

---

> For positive real constants $a$, $b$, and $c$, prove
> $$\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{a}{\pi(x^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2+b^2+c^2-2cx\cos \theta}}~dx~d\theta=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2}}.$$

I tried to use the substitution  $x=a\tan\theta$. But it does not help a lot. Please guide. Any answer will be highly appreciated.

---

Solutions posted in MSE are based on Fourier transform methods which sometimes are beyond the scope of undergraduate courses.
I would like to see if solutions based on more traditional Calculus methods can be found.

Answer (score 17):

The proposed expression can be interpreted as an integral in the superior half-plane in polar coordinates $(\rho,\theta)$. It is transformed below into cartesian coordinates $(x=\rho\cos\theta,y=\rho\sin\theta)$
\begin{align}
 I&=\frac{a}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{\infty} \frac{1}{(\rho^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\rho^2+b^2+c^2-2c\rho\cos \theta}}\,\rho d\rho~d\theta\\
 &=\frac{a}{2\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \frac{1}{\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2+b^2}}\,dxdy
\end{align}
Under this form, it appears as a convolution integral which can be evaluated by a 2D Fourier transform technique. The integral $I$ writes
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x,y)g(x-c,y)\,dxdy\\
 f(x,y)&=\frac{a}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\\
 g(x,y)&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+b^2}}
\end{align}
Both functions are radially symmetric, their Fourier transforms can be evaluated using [Hankel transforms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Fourier_transform_in_d_dimensions_(radially_symmetric_case)) (with $k=\sqrt{k_x^2+k_y^2}$):
\begin{align}
 \hat{f}(k_x,k_y)&=a\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(kr)}{(r^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\,rdr\\
 &=e^{-ka}\\
 \hat{g}(k_x,k_y)&=2\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{J_0(kr)}{(r^2+b^2)^{1/2}}\,rdr\\
 &=2\pi \frac{e^{-kb}}{k}
\end{align}
Then, performing the inverse Fourier transform,
\begin{align}
 I=\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(a+b)k}e^{-2i\pi k_xc}\,\frac{dk_xdk_y}{k}
\end{align}
This integral can be evaluated in polar coordinates:
\begin{align}
 I&=\int_{0}^{\infty} \int_{0}^{2\pi} e^{-(a+b)k}e^{-2i\pi kc\cos\phi}\,d\phi dk\\
 &=2\pi\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-(a+b)k}J_0(2 \pi kc)\,dk\\
 &=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2}}
\end{align}
as expected

Comment: It seems that is some explanation is needed for the Fourier transform of $f*g$ for while $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$, $g\notin L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)\cap L_2(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

Comment: That is to say, the following double integral holds. Is there a more general one? $\displaystyle\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{\left(x^{2}+y^{2}+a^{2}\right)^{3}\left[(x-p)^{2}+(y-q)^{2}+b^{2}\right]}}\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y=\frac{2\pi}{a\cdot\sqrt{\left(a+b\right)^2+p^2+q^2}}$

Answer (score 7):

This is to address  integrability issues not addressed in @PaulEnta answer to this problem.

As observed, after a change of variables using polar coordinates , the desired integral $I$ may be expressed as the convolution at $(c,0)$ of the functions
\begin{align}
f_a(x,y)&=\frac{a}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}}\\
 g_b(x,y)&= \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2+b^2}}
\end{align}
that is, $I=(f_a*g_b)(c,0)=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}f_a(x,y)g_b(c-x,-y)\,dxdy$

**Connections to well known Fourier transforms:**

1. It is known from Fourier analysis (Stein and Weiss for instance) that
   $f_a$ is related to Poisson kernel in 2D, and that it is the Fourier transform of a $L_1$ function:

Let $\Phi_a(\boldsymbol{x})=e^{-2\pi a|\boldsymbol{x}|}$, which is in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

$$
\widehat{\Phi_1}(\boldsymbol{y})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^2} e^{-2\pi i \boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{t}} e^{-2\pi|\boldsymbol{x}|},d\boldsymbol{x} =\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1}{(1+|\boldsymbol{y}|^2)^{3/2}}
$$
and so,
$$
\widehat{\Phi_a}(\boldsymbol{y})=a^{-2}\widehat{\Phi_1}(a^{-1}\boldsymbol{y})=\frac{a}{2\pi(a^2+|\boldsymbol{y}|^2)^{3/2}}=f_a(\boldsymbol{y})$$
Observed that $f_a\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$ as a simple calculation using polar coordinates shows.

2. The function $g_b$ is the Fourier transform of an $L_1$ function:

Let $\Psi_b(\boldsymbol{x})=\frac{e^{-2\pi b|\boldsymbol{x}|}}{2\pi b|x|}$ for $\boldsymbol{x}\neq\boldsymbol{0}$, which is in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

$$
\widehat{\Psi_1}(\boldsymbol{y})=\frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{1+|\boldsymbol{y}|^2}}
$$
This particular Fourier transform is computed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4082555/121671). Hence
$$
\widehat{\Psi_b}(\boldsymbol{y})=b^{-2}\widehat{\Phi_1}(b^{-1}\boldsymbol{y}) =\frac{1}{2\pi b \sqrt{b^2+|\boldsymbol{y}|^2}}=\frac{1}{2\pi b}g_b(\boldsymbol{y})
$$
Notice however that $g_b\not\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^2)$.

3. By Young's convolution theorem $f_a*g_b\in\mathcal{C}_\infty(\mathbb{R}^2)$. In order to invoke the Fourier inversion theorem, some integrability considerations are in order:

---

**Lemma:** Assume $\Phi,\Psi\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and $\widehat{\Phi}\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then $\Phi\cdot\Psi\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$, and
\begin{align}
\widehat{\Phi\cdot\Psi}=\widehat{\Phi}*\widehat{\Psi}\tag{1}\label{one}
\end{align}
***Proof:*** The Fourier inversion theorem for $L_1$ implies that $\Phi$ is almost surely equal to function (which we still denote by $\Phi$) in $\mathcal{C}_\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\cap L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and
$$
\Phi(\boldsymbol{x})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{\Phi}(\boldsymbol{y})e^{2\pi i \boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{y}}\,d\boldsymbol{y}
$$

It follows that  $\Phi\cdot\Psi\in L_1(\mathbb{R}^n)$ and so,

\begin{align}
\widehat{\Phi\cdot\Psi}(\boldsymbol{t})=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Phi(\boldsymbol{x})\Psi(\boldsymbol{x}) e^{-2\pi\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{t}}\,d\boldsymbol{x}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Psi(\boldsymbol{x}) e^{-2\pi\boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{t}}\Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{\Phi}(\boldsymbol{y})e^{2\pi i \boldsymbol{x}\cdot\boldsymbol{y}}\,d\boldsymbol{y}\Big)
\,d\boldsymbol{x}
\end{align}
Since $(\boldsymbol{x},\boldsymbol{y})\mapsto \Psi(\boldsymbol{x})\widehat{\Phi}(\boldsymbol{y})$ is in $L_1(\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^n)$, we can apply Fubini's theorem to obtain
\begin{align}
\widehat{\Phi\cdot\Psi}(\boldsymbol{t})= \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{\Phi}(\boldsymbol{y}) \Big(\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\Psi(\boldsymbol{x})e^{-2\pi i \boldsymbol{x}\cdot(\boldsymbol{t}-\boldsymbol{y})}\,d\boldsymbol{x}\Big)
\,d\boldsymbol{y}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}\widehat{\Phi}(\boldsymbol{y}) \widehat{\Psi}(\boldsymbol{t}-\boldsymbol{y})\,d\boldsymbol{y}=\widehat{\Phi}*\widehat{\Psi}(\boldsymbol{t}).
\end{align}

**Remark:** The equality in \eqref{one} equality among continuous functions (pointwise).

---

4. Now that we have taken all integrability considerations out of the way, we can proceed as in @PaulEnta's (our lemma outlines the strategy)
   \begin{align}
   f_a*g_b(t_1,t_2)&=2\pi b\widehat{\Phi_a\cdot\Psi_b}(t_1,t_2)=2\pi b\int_{\mathbb{R}^2}\frac{e^{-2\pi|\boldsymbol{x}|(a+b)}}{2\pi b|\boldsymbol{x}|}e^{-2\pi i\boldsymbol{x}\cdot(t_1,t_2)}\,d\boldsymbol{x}\\
   &=2\pi(a+b)\widehat{\Psi_{a+b}}(t_1,t_2)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2+t^2_1 + t^2_2 }}
   \end{align}

Comment: Thank you @OliverDiaz, you have clearly solved the problem, much better than I could have done. I was trying to justify the calculation using the Fourier transforms of distributions, but it's a bit old for me. It's a shortcut that is used a lot in physics.

Answer (score 5):

Rewrite the integral in Cartesian coordinates

\begin{align}
I
= & \frac a\pi\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(x^2+y^2+a^2)^{3/2}} \frac{dxdy}{\sqrt{(x-c)^2+y^2+ b^2}}\\
\end{align}
Substitute $y=\sqrt{(x-c)^2+b^2} \sinh t$

$$I= \frac a\pi\int_0^\infty \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{1}{[(x\cosh t + c \>\text{sech}t)^2+b^2\sinh^2 t + c^2\tanh^2 t]^{3/2}} dx \>dt
$$

Substitute $u= x\cosh t + c \>\text{sech}\>t $ and integrate  over $u$ with
$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac{du}{(u^2+p^2)^{3/2} }= \frac2{p^2}
$

$$I
=\frac {2a}\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{\cosh t}{a^2+(a^2+b^2+c^2)\sinh^2 t + b^2\sinh^4 t}dt\\
$$
Substitute $s=\cosh t$ and then integrate over $s$ to obtain
\begin{align}
I=\frac {2a}\pi\int_0^\infty \frac{ds}{a^2+(a^2+b^2+c^2)s^2 + b^2s^4}
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(a+b)^2+c^2}}
\end{align}

Comment: (+1) Your'sseems tome the only solution that does without Fourier Analysis.